# How can i check if youtube video is playable or not?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, youtube, youtube-api

This way i can tell if the video is still processing or finished the process.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Youtube_Player
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            try
            {
                axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = "https://www.youtube.com/v/mymovieid0&autoplay=1";
            }
            catch(Exception error)
            {
                string er = error.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the video is still in process i see on youtube.com site a message that it's still processing the video:

[image: Processing]

But in my program when i'm running it i just see this circle like it's trying to play the video but since it's in process it does nothing but keep trying:

[image: Processing in my program]

The try catch i tried to do in my program is not working like i thought it will.
I need somehow to check if the video is playable and if not then it's still processing and if it does and then the process is over.

I'm trying this playing only after in my other project i checked that my video was uploaded successfully to youtube only then i want to try to check if the video is playable or not.

In my project that upload first the video i'm using youtube api v3 and i didn't find there how to check the processing status it's known problem that it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

The `Videos` resource has a property called `processingStatus` that has what you want. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#processingDetails):

> **ProcessingDetails.processingStatus**- The video's processing
>   status. This value indicates whether YouTube was able to process the
>   video or if the video is still being processed.
>
> Valid values for this property are:
>
> - Failed – Video processing has failed. See ProcessingFailureReason.
> - **Processing** – Video is currently being processed. See ProcessingProgress.
> - **Succeeded** – Video has been successfully processed.
> - Terminated – Processing information is no longer available.

So if you use [`videos.list()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) and specify `part=processingDetails` and include the ID of the video you want to check to see if it's finished processing or not.

Comment: Could you show me example how to work with it ? In the link there is not example for .net and i didn't find how to use the videos.list i can't find videos at all. I have the class Video of the api but not videos.